# Meteor.js Google Oauth issues

Tags: oauth, meteor

I am trying to setup my Meteor app to use Google logins,
Here is my setup in the /server/config.js file

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
service: "google"
  });


Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
service: "google",
clientId: "XXXXXXX",
secret: "XXXXXX"
  });
```

I have the setup on google pointed to localhost:3000
I have accounts-ui and accounts-google installed on my meteor app.

and I see the google login button on my app's homepage but when I click it I get:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch The redirect URI in the request: 
http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google?close 
did not match a registered redirect URI
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Nitrous.io since I am developing on Windows. This article explains why google sees the wrong URI.

https://github.com/shoebappa/vagrant-meteor-windows/issues/9

Basically you need to launch meteor with a modified ROOT_URL so that it doesn't start with localhost.

Replace localhost.meteor.com with the URL that meteor is actually running at. 
ROOT_URL=http://localhost.meteor.com meteor

Answer (score 6):

You have to register the redirect URL with Google's APIs Console. [Log on to the console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and check what redirect URI was set up. Add localhost if necessary

**Update:**

I tried it myself and added

```
 http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google?close
```

in the API console. I added accounts-google and accounts-ui to the Hello World app and added the login button to the page

```
<body>
    {{loginButtons}}
    {{> hello}}
</body>
```

I agreed to the requested permissions in the pop up and was logged in.

Comment: In the google console I have:
`
Client ID: ****
Email address: ****
Client secret:****
Redirect URIs: http://localhost:3000
JavaScript origins: http://localhost:3000
`  Still not working, thanks for replying, do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Another idea : Did you removed the autopublish ?
If so, you must publish the userData so your client can access to Users.

Comment: I misspelled autopublish while removing and this was causing the issue. Now its resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on https://gotlog.in
When I put https://gotlog.in/_oauth/google?close as the call back URL it get worth :

401. That’s an error.
     Error: invalid_client
     no application name

And whe I put the good call back (https://gotlog.in/_oauth/google) as said in the setup popup I get the same :

400. That’s an error.
     Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
     The redirect URI in the request: https://gotlog.in/_oauth/google?close did not match a registered redirect URI.

My root URL is setup and valid, but I have no userData published. But the documantation says : "By default, the current user's username, emails and profile are published to the client."

## Edit: found the solution here : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2717

I was missing the consent screen information in the api console. And yes the callback URL has to have the '?close' at the end. Viva Meteor =)