# Using Meteor Google Auth with Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use Meteor Google Auth with Google Drive API but meteor auth give only an access token, and Google Drive need a lots of other information (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-nodejs like clientID, clientSecret, ...).
It's possible to send directly the access token into this function ?

```
 var drive = google.drive({ version: 'v2', auth: auth });
```

Thank's a lot!

Comment: If you register with google developers console https://console.developers.google.com, you will get client_id,client_secret for your application. check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-auth and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960606/meteor-js-google-oauth-issues

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that demo I would use settings by running `meteor --settings client_secret.json` and then inside your code:

`authorize(Meteor.settings.web, listFiles);`